# Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2008.3.1105.35

Tags: c#, telerik, dependencies, versioning

OK this is driving me crazy.

The GAC only seems to contain 2014.1.403.45, the .dll I publish is 2014.1.403.45, it's a new web app in a subfolder of another web app but with its own v4.0 pipelined application pool.  The fusion log, when trying to run this joker, says:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2008.3.1105.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/PreferredPartners/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\PreferredPartners\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\PreferredPartners\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2008.3.1105.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/temp/preferredpartners/2313acbd/d597ac57/Telerik.Web.UI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/temp/preferredpartners/2313acbd/d597ac57/Telerik.Web.UI/Telerik.Web.UI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/PreferredPartners/bin/Telerik.Web.UI.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out where it is coming up with 2008.3.1105.35.  I don't see that version in the GAC, I don't see it referenced in my project file, my web.config, or anywhere else in my project.  This problem doesn't occur on my dev machine, only when I publish to our test server.  My publish settings have it wipe out the directories before it deploys.  I really don't understand what the fusion log is telling me for this either.  I know it's looking for the wrong version, but *why*?

- I have restarted IIS.
- I have cleared the temp files.
- I have reinstalled Telerik.
- Everywhere I could find the assembly generically referenced, I strong-named it to the exact version.
- I have added the following lines to my web.config:

(removed unrelated elements)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
        <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.1.403.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121FAE78165BA3D4" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
<runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI"
                          publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2014.1.403.45" newVersion="2014.1.403.45" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

It's still looking for 2008.3.1105.35.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved it up out of the other website and it started working.  I would have assumed that having a separate app pool would allow it to be treated differently; apparently I would be wrong in that assumption.